# Kotlin native - share networking, sqlite database and logic between ios and android

Tags: kotlin-multiplatform, kotlin-native

I am trying to share code between iOS and Android and looking at Kotlin. Is it possible to do sqlite database access, parallel network calls api calls, json parings and some algorithms in Kotlin Native and Kotlin Multiplatform?

I have test project with Flutter/Dart where it works but I would prefer to use Kotlin.

Thanks

Comment: I think this is possible, not sure about some exact samples. For the beginning, have a look at [this](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinconf-spinner) project. It is complicated a bit but has some things from your list. Also one can have a look at [this](https://github.com/AAkira/Kotlin-Multiplatform-Libraries) list of MPP libraries, maybe some of them will be useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try https://github.com/icerockdev/moko-template/ - here sample with network, serialization, shared business logic, storage.
for database use https://github.com/cashapp/sqldelight
multithreading can be done with https://github.com/Autodesk/coroutineworker (if you want coroutines) or https://github.com/badoo/Reaktive (if you want Rx)